# JQuery-display home.html after short intro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a intro for a website using jquery into the index.html file. I "fadeIn" and "fadeOut" some .jpg images in a row. So, after this ends, I want to load an html file which will be the "home page" and the browser url will change from "www.blabla.com" to "www.blabla.com/home.html" and if the user refresh the browser it won't play the intro again, just appear "www.blabla.com/home.html".
I use the code you see below to load the home.html after the intro ends, but it seems to appear from the beginning in the back of the page and if refresh the page intro plays again.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
                    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#image1").delay(0000).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");    
        });
                    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#image2").delay(3000).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");    
        });
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#image3").delay(6000).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");    
        });
         $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#home").delay(10000).fadeIn("slow").load('home.html');       
        });
      });
```

```
 <div id="intro>
        <div id="image1"></div>
        <div id="image2"></div>
        <div id="image3"></div>  
     </div>
     <div id=main></div>
```

How can i change this?

Comment: Just as a usability note: If I have to sit through an intro before being allowed on your site, I'm just going to leave

Comment: agree ...intro's are over and done with in this day and age of instant connectivity. People want content, not bells and whistles

Comment: I agree too. But I was just asked to make it.

Comment: javascript doesn't retain any state between page loads, so will need to store somehting to tell you not to show it, choices are cookie, localStorage, or send user status to server and store there using ajax to send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a callback function to your final fadeOut and use plain Javascript to redirect the browser to home.html. Just make sure that that page actually exists.

I've also streamlined your code as all of the document ready bits weren't needed inside of `$(function(){ ... });`

```
$(function() {
        $("#image1").delay(0000).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
        $("#image2").delay(3000).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
        $("#image3").delay(6000).fadeIn("slow").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
             window.location.href = "home.html";
        });    
    });
  });
```

Let me know if you have any questions.